# Error when i install Bazel in a RaspBerry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, bazel

Im trying yo install bazel-0.8.0 in my raspberry pi 3, but when i compile bazel, after an hour, through me an error. The specific error i think is package-bazel.sh zip: doesnt found. I follow the instruction of this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqCnW_2XDw8", and i do all the things like the video, but i cant fix that error that appears to me. Anybody know why i get that error?

This is the exactly error i get:[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems as the programm zip is not installed. Please try to execute the command line to install all prerequisits as mentioned here https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html#unix-like-systems